# How do I make settings in 1 scene affect other scene?

Tags: python, game-engine, scene

I am making a game and I wanted to find out, how to make a settings in 1 scene to affect (example, volume) other scene. Is it possible to import data from python and set it to other scene? I need to import a property from 1 scene and paste it in other scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the thing is easy using globalDict:

```
def set():
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    bge.logic.globalDict["item"] = cont.owner["item"]
def cell1get():
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    item = bge.logic.globalDict.get("item")
    cont.owner["item"] = item
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send a message to objects in other scenes.

[image]

You then use a message sensor to receive the message.

Comment: Will theese changes save when I switch between a lot of scenes? If not, how to make them save in that session?

Comment: Could you, please, upload a .blend example, if you have a free time?:)

Comment: I got question- what is subject?

Comment: I tested it- it does not save when I switch between scenes. When I switched to other scene, it did not copy property.